# Convert all music files in a folder to a specific format, preserving folder hierarchy, in OS X?

Tags: macos, audio, mp3

I have a music collection that is slightly too big for my car stereo to handle. However it is also mostly 256 kbit/s MP3. My plan now is to convert all tracks to 192 kbit/s MP3. Then they will all fit.

My library is organized in folders, and I would like to preserve that hierarchy.

How do I convert all tracks to 192 kbit/s MP3 and put them in the same folder hierarchy in a different root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself using a small python script and lame. Here is the python script:

```
import os
import sys
from os.path import join
from subprocess import call

class Converter:
    def convert(self, in_file_name, out_file_name):
        if os.path.isfile(out_file_name):
            return

        out_dir = os.path.dirname(out_file_name)
        if not os.path.isdir(out_dir):
            print '!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
            print 'creating ' + out_dir
            print '!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
            os.makedirs(out_dir)

        print 'now converting ' + in_file_name + ' to ' + out_file_name

        call(['lame', '-h', in_file_name, out_file_name])

    def _is_supported_audio_format(self, format):
        return format.lower() in ['mp3', 'aac']

    def copyAndConvertAll(self, in_root, out_root):
        originalRoot = None
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(in_root):
            # to ensure we get the correct path, not just something relative
            if originalRoot == None:
                originalRoot = root

            for file in files:
                if self._is_supported_audio_format(file[-3:]):
                    targetFileName = join(out_root, join(root, file)[len(originalRoot):])
                    self.convert(join(root, file), targetFileName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    converter = Converter()
    converter.copyAndConvertAll(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

just call it via python convert.py [source dir] [target dir], e.g. python convert.py /Users/MyUser/Music /Users/MyUser/ConvertedMusic

Answer (score 0):

xAct will bulk edit your MP3's.  Just Google for osx batch mp3 conversion and you can find all matter of utilities that will handle this for you.